# Representing a class that is a property of another class in RDF Schema using N3

Tags: rdf, rdfs, n3

I have the folowing RDF Schema

```
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix mynamespace: <http://example.com/example#>.

example:Car 
a rdfs:Class .

example:Wheel
a rdfs:Class .

example:size
a rdf:Property;
rdfs:domain example:Wheel .
```

Now I want to say that the wheel is a property of the car, but also that it is a class. How can I do that?

Comment: Why would wheel be a property?  Wouldn't you instead have something like `hasWheel a rdfs:Property ; rdfs:domain Car ; rdfs:range Wheel` ?

Comment: @Joshua Taylor, this is a good aproach, but what abaout the _size_ property of the Wheel?

Comment: What do you mean?  `hasSize a Property ; domain Wheel ; range int .  ` what's the matter with that?